# How would you create categorical "bins" for a boxplot over time in R?

Tags: r

Been working on this and haven't been able to find a decent answer.

Basically, I've got a dataset of NBA Player height vs draft year, and I am trying to create a boxplot to show how player height has changed overtime (this is for a hw assignment, so a boxplot is necessary). My dataset (`nba_data`) looks like the table below, but I have 10k rows ranging from players drafted in the 60s all the way to the 2000s.

| player_name | draft_year | height_in |
| --- | --- | --- |
| player_a | 1998 | 76 |
| player_b | 1972 | 81 |
| player_c | 2012 | 79 |

So far the closest I've gotten is

```
ggplot(data = nba_data, aes(x = draft_year, 
                            y = height_in, 
                            group = cut(x = draft_year, breaks = 5)))  + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

And this is the result I get. As far as I understand, breaks being set to 5 should separate my years into 5 year buckets, right?
[image: crappy R boxplot]

I created the same graph in Excel to get an idea of what it should look like:
[image: good r graph]

I also attempted to create categories with cut, but was unable to apply it to my boxgraph. I mostly code in Python, but have to learn R for a class at school - any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit: Another question I guess would be how the "Undrafted" players would fit into this, since R seems to want to coerce the draft_year column as numerical to fit into a box plot.

Answer (score 1):

From the `?cut` help page, the `breaks` argument is:

> `breaks`
> either a numeric vector of two or more unique cut points or a single number (greater than or equal to 2) giving the number of intervals into which `x` is to be cut.

You gave it a single number, so that's interpreted as the number of intervals.

Instead, you should give it a vector of exact breakpoints, something like `breaks = seq(1960, 2020, by = 5)`.

I'm surprised you think your axis is being numericized--it's definitely a continuous axis, but I've never heard of `ggplot` doing that to a string or factor input--check your data frame to make sure the "Undrafted" rows are really there, they might have gotten dropped or converted to `NA` at some point. But that's a good thing for `cut`, because `cut` will only work on numerics. I'd suggest cutting the column as numeric to create a `bin` column, and then replace `NA`s in the `bin` column with `"Undrafted"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a package, you can get the effect you want with:

```r
library(santoku)

ggplot(..., aes(..., group = chop_width(draft_year, 5)))
```